# How to stop a Thread if another one identical starts

Tags: android, multithreading

Every time the user presses a button, the following code is executed.

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        aA = new albumArt(foo.getField("albumArt"),albumArt.GLOSSY_1, albumart,getBaseContext());
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                    aA.placeAlbumArt();
            }
        });
    }
}.start();
```

There's a problem with this:

For example:
User presses the button => Image A starts to get downloaded.
User presses the button (before Image A has finished) => Image B starts to get downloaded.

Image B finishes (**before Image A**) to get downloaded and then it's shown (with `aA.placeAlbumArt()`).
Image A finishes and replaces Image B.

How can I avoid that Image A replaces Image B if it finishes later?

I mean, is there any way I can cancel a Thread (Image A) if another one (Image B) gets started before the first one finishes?

That would also help not to queue a lot of clicks and doing the whole process uselessly. I mean, if the user presses the button before Image A has finished, there's no point in finishing to process Image A. If the user presses the button 5 times before Image A finishes, there's no point in downloading Image A, B, C and D. It should only download E (the fifth click).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) then you could [cancel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) it.  You should be able to swap your Thread out for an AsyncTask without too much trouble.

Comment: I've fnially used an ArrayList of AsyncTasks.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can disable the click on the button , until the image A is downloaded , and then , enable the clic again in order to let the user download the second image B , and so on .

and while downloading the image A or B or ... etc, you can display a sweet msg to tell the user to wait , example : waiting .... etc

Comment: That can't help because the user must be able to press the button whenever he wants and not to wait for the Image X to be downloaded.

Comment: just for ur informations :) , if you have launched two threads , u will not be able to show the image A before image B because it can be the thread 2 is the first one who has finished the downloaded , 
the only way  that u can do is to make the user wait until the download of each image finished , or u can add an Array of threads , and add listener to force the thread [i] to wait for the end of the thread[i-1] to avoid that problem ,:)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: Put your thread in a static variable of type Thread. Interrupt it if it's not null before creating one.